# How do I update service Fabric application parameter using powershell

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Using powershell is there a way to update Service Fabric application parameters directly without have to redeploy the whole application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the applications ports you need to update the Application Manifest file and push that update to the cluster. For example, using visual studio you can make changes and when you select Publish, you can chose to update the app.

You can of course use PowerShell to apply the changes but the processes are all the same. You make changes to the manifest and update that file to the cluster. There is not an option to simply update a port using powershell like you can on an Azure VM

You can read more about updating the application manifest in the below docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/update-servicefabricservice?view=azureservicefabricps

Comment: Just to clarify when you say application port you mean by the application parameters like highlighted above in the screenshot like key, database, Endpoint. I was hoping to be able to update just one of these parameters without having to do a whole deployment. for example something along the likes of updating instance count Update-ServiceFabricService -Stateless fabric:/myapp/test -InstanceCount 1 but for parameters. I do not have to publish the whole project for that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you do not use default services, you can update the parameters.

```
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName $applicationName -ApplicationTypeVersion $applicationVer `
-Monitored -FailureAction Rollback -UpgradeDomainTimeoutSec 360 -HealthCheckRetryTimeoutSec 10 -ApplicationParameter $parameters -Force
```

*If you are using the default services of the application manifest then we recommend that you do not since as you have mentioned you have to change the manifest to deploy new settings. If you want a more ops way of doing things, then you can remove the default services and use Update-ServiceFabricService to change the parameters on the fly. Generally we recommend default services only for dev/test.*

src: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/114#issuecomment-269797023